# How to update node and npm on my live ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have rather old version of node and npm on my live server under Digital ocean

```
node -v
v8.17.0

npm -v
6.13.4
lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
4.15.0-122-generic x86_64
```

Have I just to remove old versions, reboot OS and run :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

As I have some vue/cli app on my live server Have I to rebuild them all ?

Are there some other steps I have to take ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out that you have some live vue/cli app on server, please be sure before doing an update as it might cause problems to your existing apps if it is live and serving customers currently.

Apart from this you can go with any of the following ways to update Node (and npm).

1. Use `n` module from npm as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/480642/626243).
2. Via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). First [install](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating) the nvm and then you can [install the Node](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#usage) upto latest version.

Comment: Thanks! I run command in the first link : sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable  and restarting OS I got last version : # node -v
v14.15.1  . I checked my  vue/cli app and looks it works ok...  I suppose that next time I run yarn run build it will be rebuilded with new node/npm version ?

Comment: I guess yes. Because, `14.15.1` is the version now you have by default. - @mstdmstd